# Designing a database for querying by dates?

Tags: mongodb, database

For example, I need to query the last 6 months by the earliest instance for each day (and last day by earliest instances in each hours, and last day by minutes). I was thinking of using MongoDB and having a nested structure like

```
year:{ month:{ day: { hour: { minute: [array of seconds]
```

But to get the first instance I would have to sort the array which is costly. Is there an easier way?

Comment: I really can't see the ratio behind the nested structure. A simple timestamp could also be indexed.

Comment: By the way, just to clarify, the info with the dates are not already sorted and they are 5-10 seconds apart. I was thinking of making it nested so that I could query by year, month, day, then 0th hour, 0th minute, and then I would just have an array of seconds to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Would be better just to have a `date` field.

And query to be something like:

```
find(date: {$gt : 'starting_date', $lt : 'ending_date'})
```